# c# For loop getting faster with Console.Writeline afterwards

Tags: c#, for-loop

I wrote a test program to see how much faster different kind of loops with pointers are and encountered a strange behaviuor where if i add a `Console.WriteLine("1: " + sum)` after the first loop some of the loops get faster and another becomes slower.
So how does this affect the perfomance of the loop because it seems like it does not interact with the loops at all.
My example code has the line which affects loop perfomance commented out to show the normal performance and if I uncomment it the speed changes.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            c.Do();
        }
    }

public class Class1
    {

        public unsafe int n = 1000000000;
        public unsafe int[] arr;

        public Class1 ()
        {
            arr = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = 2;
            }
        }

        public void Do ()
        {
            
            int sum = 1;
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += arr[i];
            }
            sw.Stop();
            //Console.WriteLine("1: " + sum);
            Console.WriteLine("1: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            
            unsafe
            {
                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    sum += arr[i];
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("2: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                sum = 0;
                fixed (int* start = arr)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                    {
                        sum += *(start + i);
                    }
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("3: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                sum = 0;
                fixed (int* start = arr)
                {
                    int* iter = start;
                    var remaining = arr.Length;
                    while (remaining-- > 0)
                    {
                        sum += *iter;
                        iter++;
                    }
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("4: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


                sw.Reset();
                sw.Start();
                sum = 0;
                fixed (int* start = arr)
                {
                    int* end = start + n;
                    int* iter = start - 1;
                    while (iter++ < end)
                    {
                        sum += *iter;
                    }
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("5: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
1: 2082 
2: 2038 
3: 1800 
4: 2061 
5: 1724
```

output with uncommented line:

```
1: 2000000000 
1: 1949 
2: 1953
3: 1998 
4: 2055 
5: 1724
```

I tested it multiple times to see if it was just a random difference but it seems to be consistent.

Comment: You might get unlucky with code alignment. A better benchmark would be splitting up these pieces of code in their own methods (which are always aligned) and using [benchmarkdotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) to avoid JIT warmup overhead.

Comment: Repeat the test and you will see that the times vary strongly. This has different reasons. Other processes are running on the operating system. You are not in control of when garbage collection runs. As @JeroenMostert already mentioned there is a warm-up effect. I.e., when you run a code for the first time, it (the IL) will be complied just-in-time (JIT) to machine code. This code will be loaded to the cache memory making the second and succeeding iterations run much faster than the first one. [BenchmarkDotNet ](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) considers all these aspects. Also use Release build.

Comment: Also make sure to _use_ the result of calculations, so the optimizer won't just ditch the whole computation.